# ant design tabs .ant-tabs-tab-active class remove bottom blue border

Tags: css, reactjs, antd, ant-design-pro

I am using ant-design-react in a project. In the project, I use the "tabs" component to show the products. But I have a problem. The active "tab" in "tab"-s gets a blue border-bottom or something else. I can't figure out where this feature comes from. I did not find which element is the ::before and ::after element. How can I remove it?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The active tab's bar has the ant-tabs-ink-bar and ant-tabs-ink-bar-animated class. To remove it just override the bacground-color prop of the class in a css file and import it. (Make sure it is imported after antd/dist/antd.css)

```css
.ant-tabs-ink-bar {
  background-color: transparent;
}
```